# How to set inline hover styling for next/link component?

Tags: next.js

I used to call my custom StyledLink component over my application, with its own inline styling especially for hovering. However, since the Next upgrade to version 14, it seems impossible to style it inline.

I've tried this:

```
<Link
  href={props.href}
  style={{
    textDecoration: 'none',
    margin: 0,
    lineHeight: 1.25,
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: '#222',
    fontFamily: 'Inter, sans-serif',
    '&:hover': { color: '#ff3a00' },
  }}
>
  {props.children}
</Link>
```

The hover styling doesn't work anymore. I don't find any workaround, except using external classes but I don't use css at all accross my app.